# Colorir parte de um círculo SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Estou a criar um círculo em SVG. Com um ciclo `for`, quero criar várias linhas para colorir uma certa parte do círculo, sem ultrapassar o mesmo (por exemplo metade do círculo.) O ponto `x1` e `y1` da linha têm sempre o mesmo valor, alterando apenas do `x2` e `y2` de cada linha criada. Como posso resolver o problema?

Exemplo jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4un1j8mw/1/

Código-fonte:

```js
function create_circ(rayon,cx_circle,cy_circle){
    var svg = document.getElementById('svg'); 
    var newCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'circle');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'cx', cx_circle);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'cy', cy_circle);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'r', rayon);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke-width', 2);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke', 'black');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'fill', 'white');
    
    svg.appendChild(newCircle);
}
var id_circle = document.getElementById("circle");

var rayon = 100;
var diametre = rayon*2;
var cx_circle = 150;
var cy_circle = 150;

var array_x1 = [cx_circle];
var array_y1 = [cy_circle-rayon];
var array_x2 = [cx_circle];
var array_y2 = [cy_circle+rayon];

function create_line(){
    for(i=0;i<=0;i++){ //juste une ligne
        var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', array_x1[i]);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', array_y1[i]);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', array_x2[i]);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', array_y2[i]);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "line"+i);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "red");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "2");
        svg.appendChild(line);
    }
}

//ligne
var r1 = rayon-(rayon/10);  
var r2 = rayon+(rayon/10);
//var r2 = diametre+5;

//calcule sin et cos
var a = Math.sqrt(3) / 2;
console.log(a);
var b = 0.5;
var sins = [0, b, a, 1,  a,  b,  0, -b, -a, -1, -a, -b];
var coss = [1, a, b, 0, -b, -a, -1, -a, -b,  0,  b,  a];

function line_paint(){
 for(i=0;i<200;i++){ //juste une ligne
    var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', cx_circle);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', cy_circle);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2',150+(2*i));
    line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2',(cx_circle-rayon));
    line.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "l"+i);
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "yellow");
    line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "6");
    svg.appendChild(line);
}
}

var svg = document.getElementById('svg'); 

//creé circle
create_circ(rayon,cx_circle,cy_circle);
create_line();
line_paint();
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="800">
    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar **máscaras** parece a melhor opção:

```js
  
function create_circ(rayon,cx_circle,cy_circle){
    var svg = document.getElementById('svg'); 
    var newCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'circle');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'cx', cx_circle);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'cy', cy_circle);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'r', rayon);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke-width', 2);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke', 'black');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'fill', 'white');
    
    svg.appendChild(newCircle);
    
    //criar Definições de máscara
    var newDefs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
    svg.appendChild(newDefs);    
    var newMask = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'mask');
    newMask.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'maskCircle');    
    newCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'cx', cx_circle);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'cy', cy_circle);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'r', rayon);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke-width', 2);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke', 'black');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'fill', 'white');        
    newMask.appendChild(newCircle);
    newDefs.appendChild(newMask);
}
var id_circle = document.getElementById("circle");

var rayon = 100;
var diametre = rayon*2;
var cx_circle = 150;
var cy_circle = 150;

var array_x1 = [cx_circle];
var array_y1 = [cy_circle-rayon];
var array_x2 = [cx_circle];
var array_y2 = [cy_circle+rayon];

function create_line(){
    for(i=0;i<=0;i++){ //juste une ligne
        var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', array_x1[i]);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', array_y1[i]);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', array_x2[i]);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', array_y2[i]);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "line"+i);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "red");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "2");
        //line.setAttributeNS(null, 'mask', "url(#maskCircle)");//aqui a máscara não funciona bem
        svg.appendChild(line);
    }
}

//ligne
var r1 = rayon-(rayon/10);  
var r2 = rayon+(rayon/10);
//var r2 = diametre+5;

//calcule sin et cos
var a = Math.sqrt(3) / 2;
console.log(a);
var b = 0.5;
var sins = [0, b, a, 1,  a,  b,  0, -b, -a, -1, -a, -b];
var coss = [1, a, b, 0, -b, -a, -1, -a, -b,  0,  b,  a];

function line_paint(){
     for(i=0;i<200;i++){ //juste une ligne
        var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', cx_circle);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', cy_circle);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2',150+(2*i));
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2',(cx_circle-rayon));
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "l"+i);
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "yellow");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "6");
        line.setAttributeNS(null, 'mask', "url(#maskCircle)");//aqui a máscara funciona bem
        svg.appendChild(line);
    }
}

var svg = document.getElementById('svg'); 

//creé circle
create_circ(rayon,cx_circle,cy_circle);
create_line();
line_paint();
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="800">
    
</svg>
```